# Replace complex nested table layout with css

Tags: java, html, css, nested-table

I am trying to rewrite some legacy code `nested tables` with `CSS layout`. It contains `tabular data` [`reports`] as well as `layout info` such as `background color`, `row/column height/width, alignment` and so on all wrapped under nested tables. The `layout/template` is configurable by users. Hence the `html/UI` code is generated on the fly based on the `template data`  through `JAVA`. So`inline styling` is used for dynamic code generation.

I tried to use `div elements` with `display:table, table-row, table-cell` to some extend but `colspan/rowpsans` are roadblocks.

> Sample Code Snippet

```
<tr valign="top">
<td nowrap  height="45"></td>
<td nowrap ></td>
<td nowrap  colspan="2"><font color="#000000" ><b><font size="-1" face="arial"><span>Report:</span></font></b></font></td>
<td nowrap  colspan="2"><font color="#000000" ><b><font size="-1" face="arial"><span>Report ABC</span></font></b></font></td>
<td nowrap >
  <table width=367 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap>
            <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap height="100%" align="center" valign="top">
                        <font color="#000000" ><b><font  face="arial"><span>Some Report Title</span></font></b></font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td nowrap  colspan="2"><font color="#000000" ><b><font size="-1" face="arial"><span>Some title:</span></font></b></font></td>
 <td nowrap ><font color="#000000" ><b><font size="-1" face="arial"><span>Some date</span></font></b></font></td>
</tr>
```

The above code is dynamically generated from `template` using `pure JAVA` and no external `CSS` applied. Occasionally  the `UI` layout doesn't sync up with `template` layout when generated due to the complex `nested table` structure.

Can this be completely re-written using `css/div` elements or some other means?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There are good resources to convert tables to div structure online.

One good example would be: [divtable converter](http://divtable.com/converter/)

### Example:

Your example code will be transformed into 2 files (html and css):

### Html

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #000000;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Report:</span></strong></span><span style="color: #000000;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Report ABC</span></strong></span></p>
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <div class="divTable">
                    <div class="divTableBody">
                        <div class="divTableRow">
                            <div class="divTableCell"><span style="color: #000000;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Some Report Title</span></strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p><span style="color: #000000;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Some title:</span></strong></span><span style="color: #000000;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Some date</span></strong></span></p>
```

### CSS:

```
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

Any further customization needs to be hand-written, but it's a good start.

I hope it helps!